# validating html code for standardization

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is html code and fiddle for my Dropdown box and jquery slider. IT works fine on my system. But dont know why it has issue on fiddle.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/Sb3CM/1/)

When user clicks on `FLIP` dropdown menu changes to slider and vise versa.

html:

```
<div id="home" class="container division-container">
    <div class="center-container">
        <img src="logobeta.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
        <div class="subtitle">Intent from Content </div>
        <div class="magic-container">               
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" placeholder="Select category ..." />
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style= "margin-top: -10px !important;">
                      <li id="one"><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                      <li id="two"><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                      <li id="three"><a href="#">Politics</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                     <li id="four"><a href="#">Business</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                     <li id="four"><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                     <li id="four"><a href="#">Celebrity</a></li>


                      <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>

                <span class="flip">
        <a class="flipDropDown" href="#"> FLIP </a> 
                </span>
            </div>
       </div>
        <div class="magic-bar">
            <span id="rating-slider" class="ui-slider-range"></span>
            <span class="flip">
                <a href="#"> FLIP </a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have doubt whether this code is standard and each element is relative to each other or not. Is it?

I want changing or adding the position of any element in page should not reflect to position of above elements.

Currently it looks differently in FF and chrome. Apologize for not givingg working fiddle.

Comment: Other than the duplicate ID "four", which isn't referenced in the Javascript or the CSS anyway, the W3 validator doesn't find any errors in the fiddle. I can't see, however, much difference between Chrome and FF.

Comment: The amount of `!important`s worry me though. Please tell me this is a desperate attempt to get something right, and not a design pattern.